# How can I use JQuery to retrieve the reference to a div inside a variable that represent its container object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I am not so into JavaScript\JQuery and I have the following problem:

Into a page I have some `<section>` tags, something like this:

```
<section class="com__section com__section--text functionSection">
    <div></div>
</section>

<section class="com__section com__section--text functionSection">
    <div></div>
</section>

<section class="com__section com__section--text functionSection">
    <div></div>
</section>
```

Then I have a JQuery script that select one of these section (using a specific logic, but this is not important now), something like this:

```
var s = section.eq(i);
```

So `s` variable contains an object related to a specific `<section>` tag.

Now my problem is, starting from this **s** variable, how can I obtain the reference to the inner `<div>` that is inside this `<section>`? How can I correctly implement this behavior using JQuery?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what `s` would be in your situation, but if it's a jquery element, you can do `s.find('selector')` (with your desired selector) to get child element(s) of `s`.

Comment: children?  https://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this is ?

```
var div = s.find('div');
```

Hope it helps.